# Get Shipping Price From Quote

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shipping

I am trying to get the shipping price from the quote on the cart page for the entire order.

I have tried multiple things including:

```
Mage::getModel("checkout/session")->getQuote()->getShippingMethod()->getPrice();


$rates = Mage::getModel("checkout/session")->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getAllShippingRates();
foreach($rates as $rate){
    $rate->getPrice();
}
```

What can I do to get the shipping price in the Magento cart?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This will do the trick. From your question, I assume that the customer has already selected their desired shipping method.

```
<?php

$quote = Mage::getModel("checkout/session")->getQuote();
$amount = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingAmount();
```

In fact, there are a number of methods available to you. Such as:

```
<?php 

$address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$address->getBaseShippingAmount();
$address->getBaseShippingDiscountAmount();
$address->getBaseShippingHiddenTaxAmount();
$address->getBaseShippingInclTax();
$address->getBaseShippingTaxAmount();

$address->getShippingAmount();
$address->getShippingDiscountAmount();
$address->getShippingHiddenTaxAmount();
$address->getShippingInclTax();
$address->getShippingTaxAmount();
```

If you simply want to get all available shipping rates into an array:

```
<?php

$address = $quote->getShippingAddress();

$shippingPrices = array();
foreach($address->getAllShippingRates() as $rate){
    $shippingPrices[$rate->getCode()] = $rate->getPrice();
}
var_dump($shippingPrices);
```

Comment: My pleasure and good luck to you in your endeavors!